# sql count number of rows(videos) added by the CURRENT userid

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla

I have this sql code but it doesn't seem to work.
I have a video site on joomla 3.3

here is the code:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$cuid = $user->id;
$total_videos = "SELECT ('COUNT(*)') FROM #__hdflv_upload WHERE memberid = '".$cuid."'";
$db->setQuery($total_videos);
$result = $db->loadResult();
```

So what I'm trying to do is SHOW the CURRENT LOGGED IN user the number of HIS added videos.

"#__hdflv_upload" is the table containing all videos
"memberid" is the ID of the USER who ADDED the video

It seems there is an error in this whole sql query and I can't understand what it might be, can someone please help me. Thank you

Comment: Does the `memberid` match the user ID in the `#__users` table?

Comment: yep, it definitely matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've already mentioned, the `memberid` and ID of the user in the `#__users` table match, so I would recommend using the following query which uses the latest Joomla coding standards:

```
<?php
    $db   = JFactory::getDbo();
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    $cuid = $user->id;

    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select('COUNT(*)');
          ->from($db->quoteName('#__hdflv_upload'))
          ->where($db->quoteName('memberid') . ' = ' . (int)$cuid ));
    $db->setQuery($query);

    $count = $db->loadResult();

    echo $count;
?>
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: yep it does thanks a lot :) can you help me a bit more please, how can I make so the sql gives 2 results, for example, videos added in last 7 days and another one videos added in last month.. can you help please. thank you!!!